# How can I run interactive docker shell from python script

Tags: python, docker

I build script that helps get inside container in docker swarm:

```
import docker

d = docker.from_env()
s = d.services.get(args.service_name)
task = s.tasks(filters={"desired-state": "running"})
node = d.nodes.get(task[0]['NodeId'])
container_id = task[0]['Status']['ContainerStatus']['ContainerID']

print("env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://{addr}:2376 docker exec -ti {container} bash".format(addr=node.attrs['Status']['Addr'], container=container_id))
```

And now I want to run interactive shell from script itself but this doesn't work:

```
c_client = docker.DockerClient(base_url="tcp://{}:2376".format(node.attrs['Status']['Addr']))
c = c_client.containers.get(container_id)
c.exec_run("bash", stdin=True, tty=True)
```

So is there any way to run interactive shell using python and python-docker only?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, it seems, but it'll probably be pretty fiddly.

[Looks like](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.exec_run) you'll need to use `socket=True` to begin with. With that done, you'll need to connect your Python process's `stdin` and `stdout` to the socket, reading and writing as required.